# Are “dumb” AI in Halo are also vulnerable to logic plague?

Tags: halo

Ok, Smart AI are definitely vulnerable, but what about ordinary “dumb” combat AI like Auntie Dot from Halo Reach? Is she also vulnerable to Logic plague?